# SQL Update Column By Adding A Number To Current Int

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sqlcommand

Simple enough, I can't figure out how to add (that's +) an integer from a textbox to the integer in the SQL Field.

So for example, the SQL Field may have '10' in it and the textbox may have '5' in it. I want to add these numbers together to store '15' without having to download the SQL Table.

The textbox that contains the integer to be added to the SQL integer is `tranamount.Text` and the SQL Column in the SQL Table is @ugpoints. Please note, without the '+' - which is in the below code and is admittedly wrong- the value of `tranamount.Text` is added to the Table without an issue, but it simply replaces the original value; meaning the end result would be '5' in the SQL Field.

What would be the proper way to structure this? I've tried the below code, but that clearly doesn't work.

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonsA SET U_G_Studio=@ugpoints WHERE Members_ID=@recevierID", con)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recevierID", tranmemberID.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ugpoints", + tranamount.Text) '<--- Value to add.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Newbies question I know, I'm new to SQL in vb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the current value of the `U_G_Studio` field, add the value of the parameter and reassign to `U_G_Studio`, but keep in mind that you need to pass the value as an integer because otherwise the `AddWithValue` will pass a string and you get conversion errors coming from the db.

```
    cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonsA SET U_G_Studio=U_G_Studio + @ugpoints " & 
                         "WHERE Members_ID=@recevierID", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recevierID", tranmemberID.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ugpoints", Convert.ToInt32(tranamount.Text))
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. You've helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the correct sql:

```
Dim sql = "UPDATE PersonsA SET U_G_Studio=U_G_Studio + @ugpoints WHERE Members_ID=@recevierID"
```

Also use the correct type with `AddWithValue`:

```
Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    ' use the using-statement to dispose everything that implements IDisposable, so also the connection '
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ugpoints", Int32.Parse(tranamount.Text)) 
    ' .... '
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you want is:

```
"UPDATE PersonsA SET U_G_Studio= (U_G_Studio + @ugpoints) " & _
"WHERE Members_ID=@recevierID"
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ugpoints",  (int)tranamount.Text) 
....
cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonsA SET U_G_Studio= SET U_G_Studio + @ugpoints WHERE Members_ID=@recevierID", con)
```

edit1: STEVE WAS FASTER!

Comment: Thanks for your solution, though Steve was faster I appreciate your response as well.